# iphone like button flow

Tags: iphone, menu, navigation, interpolation

I'm really impressed with the way the iPhone manages scrolling lists (such as through play lists).

I was wondering how I could impelment something similar and what I should read up on before trying to? I'm more interested in the mathematics behind the motion, the interpolation and such rather than implementing it for any given system.

So I do understand it uses some form of interpolation, what I would like to know is the sort of interpolation it uses, is it as as simple as some mathematical function or does it do other things?

*edited for Tobias's questions

Comment: What do you mean by "scrolling buttons," and what platform do you want to implement it under?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a [fairly long blog post](http://www.macresearch.org/dynamics-scrolling) about it.

Also see this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810742/algorithm-to-implement-kinetic-scrolling).