# How to develop a scrollview with inertia in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I want to develop a "scrollview" in Unity.

Basically I have a Parent Game Object on the screen with many items inside it.
The Parent Game Object is big enough so it goes outside the screen.

I developed a scrolling script so when the user drags the parent object, I move it and it looks like scrolling.

I did this by implementing the OnMouseDrag event.

How can I calculate the inertia and apply it so when the user drags it fast, it continues to move?

Comment: by unity you mean the 3D game engine and editor ?

Comment: correct, Unity3d game engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want, the effect that you want, is called *kinetic scroll/scrolling/panning* .

[Here is an answer with a generic algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810742/algorithm-to-implement-kinetic-scrolling) in it, I'm sure that with this keyword in mind you will probably find a ton more of examples.

Next time watch out for the tags, your first set of tags was incorrect, other frameworks have the same *unity* name .